# Android swiping (sliding) menu (list)

Tags: android, list, swipe

I am searching for a listview (or something similar) on android like the menu used in this game:

[image: Hill climb racing menu]

I want the items to take place horizontally alongside to each other.

Any similar library would help me. For example even a cyclic one will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [3D carousel](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-3d-carousel-view/) control in android.

Comment: Thanks @mrid, this is the thing I was looking for. I was just missing the name carousel. To complete your answer for others, this project on github will be found here (https://github.com/radhoo/android-3d-carousel-view) with a tutorial here (http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html) and one similar and cyclic would be this (https://github.com/radhoo/android-3d-carousel-view).

Comment: glad it helped :) and thanks for adding similar libraries !!

Comment: Now with the name carousel I found one more: https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager